# Why does a single switch on the wall control only the fan on my ceiling fan?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I have a Harbor Breeze fan where the light switch only controls turning the fan on and off. You have to pull the chain to turn the light on. Both pull chains work fine. There is no remote control.

What is wrong? Is the wiring wrong? Could the wrong black wire be connected to the blue and the wrong black to black?

[image: ceiling wires]
[image: ceiling wires pic 2]

Comment: Do I need to drop bracket?

Comment: That would help, yes

Comment: So how are you wanting it to work?  Will the wall switch control the fan AND light, or are you wanting the wall switch to control the light, then pull chain control for the fan?

Comment: Just need wall switch to control light if thats the easier.

Comment: Im thinking the wrong black is connected to the blue. Is that possibly the case?

Comment: Even if light pull chain is on the wall outlet is only working the fan. It will not cut the light off or on

Comment: There was a ceiling fan there previously. But I did not put it up or take it down .  I'm just trying to fix this one the last one the wall switch worked the light

Comment: Answer:. Now fixed. Tan and white were neutral wires ( hooked together correctly) The blue wire (light hot wire)  from fan was not hooked to hot wire coming out of box. Just disconnected small black wire from blue (capped it off) then connected blue wire to the black coming from ceiling. Now light and fan can be controlled by switch or pull chains!!!

Comment: Basically blue wire needed to connect to hot wire and switch leg. Small black wire was a pig tail and needed to be disconnected from blue and capped off

Comment: @ConnieFieldsBarnesJohnson -- post the contents of your last two comments as an answer and I'll upvote you :)

Comment: You should be able to post your answer now. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

Answer:. Now fixed. Tan and white were neutral wires ( hooked together correctly) The blue wire (light hot wire)  from fan was not hooked to hot wire coming out of box. Just disconnected small black wire from blue (capped it off) then connected blue wire to the black coming from ceiling. Now light and fan can be controlled by switch or pull chains!!!

Answer (score 0):

If the fan is replacing a previous ceiling light, the situation you describe is the best you can expect.

The wall switch has sent, and still sends, power to the ceiling fixture when ON. The wall switch can't know that there are now two devices, fan and lights, potentially connected to that power.

It's up to the fan/light to decide where the power goes, based on the pull chains operation.

That's why some fans come with a remote control, to send power ***and*** routing information to the fan/light unit.

Comment: See new comment.